# react-admin as a page in Gatsby project

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-admin

**expecting**
I wanted to include react-admin in a Gatsby project so that I could have a /admin route that will be an interface for the site data.

**What happened instead:**
Using gatbsy new , I setup a boilerplate gatsby project. Then installing react-admin and adding a page into the gatsby project, while following [react-admin tutorial](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html), causes gatsby to fail building.

> gatsby develop

seems fine and does not crash the app, however

> gatbsy build

leads to

> WebpackError: Invariant failed

**Steps to reproduce:**
gatsby new _____
npm install react-admin
npm install ra-data-simple-rest

- add a minimal admin page to gatsby's pages folder

gatsby develop = OK
gatsby build = Failed

**terminal output**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNXhk.jpg

**Related code:**
Here is a repository that can be cloned to reproduce:
https://github.com/jzohdi/react-admin-gatsby-test

**Environment**
Same result on Windows 10 and WSL Ubuntu 18.04

from package.json
    "gatsby": "^2.22.15",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.4.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.4.9",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.2.7",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.3.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.6.9",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.3.8",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.5.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-admin": "^3.5.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.0.0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your repository, it sounds like you found the answer, but you don't like it.

Gatsby can't do SSR for react-admin because react-admin depends on running in the browser. To integrate react-admin into Gatsby, you need to generate your admin area as [client-only routes](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/client-only-routes-and-user-authentication/).

I'd expect admin areas to be client-only routes anyways, since they would require authentication to view. Populating them with real data at build-time could create data security issues.

In your example repo, you mention these ways to fix the issue. I'm going to record them here for posterity:

#### 1) Replace the offending module with a dummy during SSR <sup>[1](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/#fixing-third-party-modules)</sup>

This snippet *should* replace the react-admin module while running server-side rendering, and result in a successful compilation:

```js
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /react-admin/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

#### 2) Use `loadable-components`<sup>[2](https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components)</sup>

Instead of importing `react-admin` components directly, wrap them in the `loadable` functions. This pulls them out of the HTML-build process and keeps Gatsby from choking on it.

```js
import loadable from '@loadable/component';

const reactAdmin = loadable() => import('react-admin');
const { Admin, Resource } = reactAdmin
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get react-admin to work inside gatsby with a third strategy, by using the `react-router-dom` MemoryRouter on a static page. You won't get the browser url updated when you click resources, but it will at least build.

```js
import simpleRestProvider from 'ra-data-simple-rest';

const AdminApp = () => {
  return (
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Admin
        dataProvider={simpleRestProvider(`${API_URL}/admin`, authFetch)}
      >
        <Resource name="orders" list={OrderList} show={OrderShow} />
      </Admin>
    </MemoryRouter>
  )
};
```

It also required creating individual pages for routes login, logout and auth-callback routes, to actually handle the async functions provided by `ra-auth-auth0`. Gatsby didn't exactly make it easy to incorporate react-admin, but now it's all integrated and working nicely.